# JS: Mapping a multidimensional object into recursive arrays?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a (jibberish) multidimensional object like this:

```
tree = {
    "Russia": "vodka",
    "Ireland": "potatos",
    "France": {
        "population": "a lot",
        "states": {
            "south": "alabama",
            "north": "alaska"
        },
        "founding": 1776
    },
    "USA": {
        "population": {
            "hispanic": {
                "origin": "spain",
                "food": "tacos"
            },
            "chinese": {
                "origin": "UK",
                "food": "eggroll"
            }
        },
        "states": {
            "big": "lyon",
            "small": "paris"
        },
        "founding": 1000
    },
    "UK": {
        "population": 444343,
        "states": {
            "wht": "brick",
            "fine": "rock",
            "sta": "wine"
        },
        "founding": {
            "first conquer": {
                "vikings": 102,
                "nords": 456,
                "irish": 1000,
                "french": "everyday"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to iterate through the tree such that I have control over each "level" (if there's a standard term for this please let me know!), for instance the keys "Russia," "Ireland," "France," "USA," and "UK" would be level one. Population, states and founding would be level two, etc. Like this...

```
function treeLevels(object) {

    function onlyExecuteOnFirstLevel() {
        //some stuff
    }

    function recursion(object) {
        for (k in object) {

            //this isn't the kind of base case I need
            if (!typeof object[k] == 'object') {
                onlyExecuteonFirstLevel(); //this will run but also on undesired parts of the tree
            } else {
                recursion(object[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After reading some posts on basic recursive patterns the best solution seems to be to create arrays within arrays?

```
treeLevelsKey = [];
treeLevelsValue = [];

function onlyExecuteOnFirstLevel(level) {
    if (level == 0) {
        //stuff
    }
}

function treeLevels(object) {
    for (k in object) {

        treeLevelsKey[k] = [];
        treeLevelsValue[object[k]] = [];

        onlyExecuteOnFirstLevel(???) //the argument should be the first index of the desired array...but not sure           

        //base case
        //recursion
    }
}
```

I think recursively creating the arrays is the right way to go, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a function's argument to take stuff the code puts into the parent arrays.

Comment: At any given level, what will be the type of the values of your associative array?

Comment: Your example says that it can be either a string or an associative array, but I just want to confirm if it could be of any other type as well?

Comment: I thought that objects are associative arrays in JS? The value or key at any level/depth in the `list` object tree could be any type of value (string, integer, boolean).

Comment: but not arrays or any other objects (except associative arrays)?

Comment: Associative arrays are objects in JS, not vice-versa, I think!

Comment: Well yes...the value of any given key in a multidimensional object could be another (multidimensional) object. Isn't that why recursion is needed to iterate through the entire tree...?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve with this 'level'ing of your data? Why do you feel you need to change the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
tree = {
    "Russia": "vodka",
    "Ireland": "potatos",
    "France": {
        "population": "a lot",
        "states": {
            "south": "alabama",
            "north": "alaska"
        },
        "founding": 1776
    },
    "USA": {
        "population": {
            "hispanic": {
                "origin": "spain",
                "food": "tacos"
            },
            "chinese": {
                "origin": "UK",
                "food": "eggroll"
            }
        },
        "states": {
            "big": "lyon",
            "small": "paris"
        },
        "founding": 1000
    },
    "UK": {
        "population": 444343,
        "states": {
            "wht": "brick",
            "fine": "rock",
            "sta": "wine"
        },
        "founding": {
            "first conquer": {
                "vikings": 102,
                "nords": 456,
                "irish": 1000,
                "french": "everyday"
            }
        }
    }
};

function get_value(tree, key, level) {
    if( typeof( tree[key] ) == "object" &&
        Object.keys(tree).length >= 1 ) {
        value = tree[ key ];
        console.log(level + ":\t" + key );
        for( k in value ) {
            console.log((level + 1) + ":\t" + k );
            get_value( tree[key], k, level + 1);
        }
    } else {
        var hash = tree[ key ];
        console.log(level + ":\t" + key );
    }
}

for( key in tree ) {
    var level = 0;
    get_value( tree, key, level);
}
```

- Begin with the zero level
- Check if the value is an object or not (since you said that values can't be array, so checking for object is enough). Increase level by 1 at each call to get_value.
- If it is an object, then iterate over its keys & call get_value for each value,
  else the element doesn't have any children (or base case of the recursion).

Comment: That'll work so long as you don't need to access all the keys for a particular level at the same time.